# get only filename (exclude pathname) and record count in linux

Tags: linux

I have this linux command that does what I need it to do (get count and filename). The only problem is it outputs the entire directory path (123 dir1/dir2/sample1.txt) How can I modify to include just filename and count (123 sample1.txt)?

```
find . -type f -name "*" -exec wc -l {} \;
```

> **Getting: 123  dir1/dir2/sample1.txt**
>
> **Want: 123  sample1.txt**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try sed!

```
find . -type f -name "*.xml" -exec wc -l {} \; | sed 's/\.\/.*\///g'
```

my output had . in the beginning but if yours does not than use

```
find . -type f -name "*.xml" -exec wc -l {} \; | sed 's/\/.*\///g'
```

EDIT:  The sed basically replaces any occurrences of `./some/path/` with empty string, or if using the second example it replaces occurrences of `/some/path/`.

EDIT2:  Here is a third example that works regardless if the output has a . or not in the front of the path:

```
find / -type f -name "*.xml" -exec wc -l {} \; | sed 's/\.*\/.*\///g'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of `basename` and use a pipe:

```
find . -type f -name "*" -exec wc -l {} \; | xargs -n1 basename
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a path name, you can extract just the file name by using `basename` or, if in Bash, an expression `${##*/}`.  In your case, one way is to extract the path name first into a variable, and then call `basename` or use the expression on the variable.

Here is an example.  It is likely more complex than needed, but it should illustrate the point (and I'm sure others can point out easier ways to do this):

```
#!/bin/bash

the_results=$( find . -type f -name "*" -exec wc -l {} \; )

echo "$the_results"

#
# Run 'find' command, iterating on each line of the result.
#
# We need to set IFS to not have a space, so the two returned items are
# treated as one result.
#
# We then parse each returned item into its two fields:
#    word count (a sequence of digits),
#    a space
#    path name (anything to end of line),
#
# The built-in BASH regular expression facility is used (the "=~"
# operator).  Substrings matched by parenthesized subexpressions
# within the regular expression are saved in the array variable
# BASH_REMATCH.
#
#
IFS=$'\n\b'

for a_result in $( find . -type f -name "*" -exec wc -l {} \; );
    do
        echo "result: $a_result"
        if [[ $a_result =~ ([0-9]+)\ (.*)$ ]]; then
            echo "${BASH_REMATCH[0]}"
            echo "    ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
            echo "    ${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"

            word_count="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
            path_name="${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
            file_name="${path_name##*/}"

            echo "word_count: $word_count"
            echo "path_name: $path_name"
            echo "file_name: $file_name"
        else
            echo "Parse failed"
        fi
    done

unset IFS
```